# Use both values of $\pm$ in equations

Tags: symbolic

Is there an elegant way to use $\pm$ in equations, without having to make a text change and substitution using an `Or` function?

For instance, I would like this equation

```
Solve[x \[PlusMinus] 2 == 0, x]
```

to be solved to `{{x -> -2},{x -> 2}}`

and `Plot[\[PlusMinus] x^2, {x, 0, 1}]` to give two branches, of the form

```
Plot[{x^2, -x^2}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Should `Solve[x \[PlusMinus] 2 + Exp[ \[PlusMinus] 2] == 0, x]` denote two cases, four cases, or simply be disallowed?

Comment: Oh... I would say four cases.

Comment: This is far from a perfect response, but the way I would handle it in simple cases would be to choose "-", negate both sides, then replace "x" with Abs[x].

`Solve[2 - Abs[x] == 0, x, Reals]` gives `{{x -> -2}, {x -> 2}}`.

Comment: @josborne:  That's a help, but your approach gets very awkward when one tries to solve even something as simple as `Solve[Abs[x \[PlusMinus] 2] \[PlusMinus] 3 == 0, x]`.

Comment: What about something like `LogicalExpand@Reduce[{Abs[x + f 2] + f2 3 == 0, Abs@f == 1, Abs@f2 == 1, (f | f2) \[Element] Reals}, x]`? - Essentially this replaces `a ± b` with `a + f b && (f==1 || f==-1)`

Comment: @LukasLang:  Interesting approach, but a bit kludgy, reliant on hand analysis of the structure of the equation, and the resulting solution is rather complicated and involves `Im[x]` (fixed with `x \[Element] Reals`).  Better would be a "wrapper" function that did the analysis automatically... but even there, it is a bit kludgy.

Comment: Note that for `Plot` to plot all combinations of signs, the functions need to be in a `List`; but `Solve[{eqplus, eqminus} == 0,...]` and `Solve[{eqplus == 0, eqminus == 0},...]` implicitly join the equations with `And` and not `Or`. So the built-in syntax of `Plot` vs. `Solve`/`Reduce` leads to some incompatibility that needs to be overcome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following function performs the transformation I've suggested in the comments:

```
Options[PMReduce] = {"SynchronizePM" -> False};
PMReduce[eqns_, vars_, dom_: Complexes, OptionsPattern[]] := Module[
  {
   pEqns,
   params,
   i = 0,
   step = Boole[! OptionValue@"SynchronizePM"]
   }, {pEqns, params} = Reap[
    Flatten@{eqns} //. {
      (a_ ± b_) :> (a + Sow[C[i += step]] b),
      (a_ ∓ b_) :> (a - Sow[C[i += step]] b)
      }
    ];
  Reduce[
   Append[
    pEqns,
    And @@ (# == 1 || # == -1 & /@ First@params)
    ],
   vars,
   dom
   ]
  ]
```

The `"SynchronizePM"` option controls whether the `±` should be changed synchronously (i.e. `a±b±c` to `a+b+c||a-b-c`)

Examples:

```
PMReduce[Abs[x ± 2] ± 3 == 0, x, Reals]
(* (C[1] == -1 && C[2] == -1 && x == -1)
|| (C[1] == -1 && C[2] == -1 && x == 5)
|| (C[1] == -1 && C[2] == 1 && x == -5)
|| (C[1] == -1 && C[2] == 1 && x == 1) *)

PMReduce[Abs[x ± 2] ± 3 == 0, x, Reals, "SynchronizePM" -> True]
(* (C[0] == -1 && x == -1) 
|| (C[0] == -1 && x == 5) *)
```

Comment: Oh... very nice.  And I've tried the code on several non-obvious equations and *sets* of equations with excellent results.  (Accept)

Comment: Thanks for the accept! For completeness, I've updated the answer with an option to control whether the `±` should be changed simultaneously and added support for `∓`

Answer (score 7):

I may need to give this more thought but it seems to me you actually want [`Or`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Or.html).

For example:

```
a_: 0 ± n_ := a - n || a + n

Solve[x ± 2 == 0, x]

Solve[Abs[x ± 2] ± 3 == 0, x]
```

> ```
> {{x -> -2}, {x -> 2}}
>
> {{x -> -5}, {x -> -1}, {x -> 1}, {x -> 5}}
> ```

---

In light of your edit to include [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) we could either allow the expansion above and modify `Plot` to operate on `Or`, or we could modify both `Solve` and `Plot` (etc.) to specially handle `±`.  Doing my best to read between the lines I think you prefer the latter, so I'll illustrate that.

```
ClearAll[PlusMinus]

Plot;
Unprotect[Plot];
PrependTo[DownValues[Plot], 
  HoldPattern[Plot[expr_, arg___]] /; ! TrueQ[$plotPlusMinus] :>
    Block[{$plotPlusMinus = True}, 
      Plot[#, arg] &[expr //. a_: 0 ± n_ :> {a - n, a + n}]
    ]
];
Protect[Plot];

Plot[x + Sin[±x] ± 1/2, {x, 0, 8}]
```

[image]

**Notes**

- This assumes the plot function is composed of Listable functions; if that does not hold manual threading can be added, but I first want to know if this is moving in a direction that pleases you or not.
- I did not localize the Plot variable(s).  That can be done but again I first want to know if this is going to be useful.

Comment: Perhaps... but my question stated:  "...without having to make a text change and substitution using an `Or` function"

Comment: @DavidG.Stork But I don't understand; why would you avoid `Or` if it is actually the solution?  I tried to provide syntactic sugar to that end, though I'm sure you were capable as well.  I feel like I'm missing something here; I was hoping you'd provide an example where this fails.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Perhaps you want `±` to expand only inside of `Solve`?

Comment: `Solve` was just one function that needs to handle `\{PlusMinus`, but there are many others, e.g., `Plot[\PlusMinus] x^2, {x, 0, 1}]`, `Simplify`, etc.

Comment: @David wouldn't it be best to overload each of these functions for ±?  I don't see how one universal expansion can address your needs.

Comment: @MrWizard.  I too don't see immediately how a universal expansion can be used, but I thought I'd search.  The substitution with `Or` seemed straightforward, but @LukasLang's solution was superior (as far as I could see).  Perhaps *Wolfram* should incorporate `\[PlusMinus]` much the way they have handled automatically `Which` and other function partition methods.

Comment: @David Isn't this notation often used to describe an interval rather than two discrete values?  I think a different notation is needed for the latter if it is going to be integrated.  Maybe `Plot[3 || 7, {x, 0, 5}]` should give the same output as `Plot[{3, 7}, {x, 0, 5}]`?  Anyway you said Lukas's solution is superior, and it probably is, but could you give me an example where it works and mine does not?

Comment: I don't know of an application where Lukas' solution works and yours does not, but he was 40 minutes earlier than you, works fine for all my cases, and hence he gets the accept.  Thanks for your "polishing" of his key insight, though!

Comment: @MichaelE2 What output is that giving you?  In v10.1 I get a bunch of `ConditionalExpression` which I'm guessing you were working to avoid.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I would point out that you can't really avoid `Or` (well, without, say, mapping `Solve` over the alternatives).  Note Lukas's solution does not avoid `Or`: it takes and sticks in the `Or`'s after reaping the text-replaced alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

Little improving magnificent code from [user Lukas Lang](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/36508/lukas-lang):

```
SOLVE[eqns_, vars_, dom_: Complexes] := {{ToRules[Module[{pEqns, params, i = 0}, {pEqns, params} = 
Reap[Flatten@{eqns} //. (a_ \[PlusMinus] b_) :> (a + Sow[f[i++]] b)];
Reduce[Append[pEqns, And @@ (# == 1 || # == -1 & /@ First@params)], vars, dom]]]}[[All, -1]]}


SOLVE[x ± 2 == 0, x]
(* {{x -> 2, x -> -2}} *)

SOLVE[Abs[x ± 2] ± 3 == 0, x, Reals]
(* {{x -> -1, x -> 5, x -> -5, x -> 1}} *)
```